# How do I fix a nested DB call error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, post

I have a JavaScript loop that loops through elements with the class "Amount Field," and I am making a post call to a servlet within that loop.

Occasionally, I get a Nested DB Error. I tried adding a timeout, but I still sometimes get the error.

The code is below:

```
$('.AmountField').each(function(i, obj) {
    var donationId = ($(obj).attr('id')).substring(14);
    console.log(donationId);
    var data = {
        userId: userId,
        date: $("#donationDate").val(),
        amount: +$(obj).val(),
        method: $("#paymentMethod").val(),
        bank: $("#Account").val(),
        referredBy: $("#referredBy").val(),
        donationId: donationId,
        //description: $("#Description").val(),
    };
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post("ActionReceivePaymentsServlet", $.param(data), function(response) {
            alert("Donation Entered Successfully");
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Is there any way that I could fix this issue? I am using an sqlite database if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I can only conclude that the database is a web based API to which you're sending your request.

setTimeout() won't have any effect on the execution of the POST request, it'll simply delay the execution for at least 1000 milliseconds.

In your case you are simply sending a client request to the database and you have no control over the error that happens inside the database. Your only option would be to handle this error appropriately in your JavaScript application.

From the jQuery.post() documentation page,

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by **$.get()** implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information). The **jqXHR.done()** (for success), **jqXHR.fail()** (for error), and **jqXHR.always()** (for completion, whether success or error; added in jQuery 1.6) methods take a function argument that is called when the request terminates.

Therefore your code would look like

```
$.post("ActionReceivePaymentsServlet", $.param(data), function(response) {
  alert("Donation Entered Successfully");
}).fail(function (error) {
  alert("Donation Failed");
});
```